# Animate a change in UIFont size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, core-animation

Is there a way to animate a change in the font size of some text.  I was thinking to call drawRect from a subclass of UIView and draw the text at different sizes.

Comment: What do you mean saying animate Font size ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: E.g. if the font is 20 and he wants to animate it all the way down to 10px.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can font size of UILabel be changed with smooth animation on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098893/can-font-size-of-uilabel-be-changed-with-smooth-animation-on-iphone)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can animate the transform on any UIView including labels.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

That will scale the text up to 150%. It may become blocky if you make it too big.

Comment: Beautiful. Pair this with a drop shadow and it looks like the text is really jumping out at you. It's a neat effect. Thanks for the code skorulis.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:self.view];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
label.font = [UIFont font...]; //try setting the font and the size you want
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: This will not work. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1 does not list font as an animatable property.